# Aggregating multiple models in to one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to add a `has_many` which will return an ordered collection of different types, similar to a polymorphic association.

```
class Group < AR:Base
  has_many ??
end

class Picture < AR::Base; belongs_to :group; end
class Video   < AR::Base; belongs_to :group; end
class Audio   < AR::Base; belongs_to :group; end
```

How do I have group return all the pictures, videos and audio which `belong_to` it using SQL. I don't really want to have to resort to using Ruby since I also want to have the collection of 'media items' ordered with `acts_as_list` or similar.

Comment: I am not sure about acts as list, but something on the lines should be possible with the use of a join table(polymorphic) and includes.

Answer (score 0):

Use STI (single table inheritance).

```
class Group < AR:Base
  has_many :media_items
end

class MediaItem < AR::Base; belongs_to :group; end
class Picture < MediaItem; end 
class Video   < MediaItem; end
class Audio   < MediaItem; end
```

You just need to add the `type` column to your DB schema for that.